# Detect a toolTip launch java

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

Hey,
is there any way to detect the launch of a tool tip on a swing component in Java?
Cant even think where to start on this one.
cheers

Comment: Can you think to explain the actual goal here?  That is often more productive than asking how to achieve a flawed strategy intended to achieve a valid goal, which this might well be.

Comment: the goal here is to detect when a tooltip is launched and for how long it is viewed so that i can log this data as it is part of a research platform that my team and I are writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite the [createTooltip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#createToolTip%28%29) method on your specific component, adding the [JTooltip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html) element returned a [ComponentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html).

As an example:

```
   final ComponentListener customTooltipListener=new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            // whatever you need on this event
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            // whatever you need on this event
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            // whatever you need on this event

        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            // whatever you need on this event

        }
    };          

    JButton button=new JButton("Command") {

        @Override
        public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            //keep default behaviour 
            JToolTip toReturn=super.createToolTip();
            toReturn.addComponentListener(customTooltipListener);
            return toReturn;
        }

    };
```

That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

My short investigation showed the following.

Class responsible on the tooltip appearance is TootipManager. All components use its shared instance, so this manager is singleton. You cannot intercept creating this manager and it does not throw events that you can catch. But when manger decides to show the tooltip it calls `getToolTipText()` from the component. So, if you wish to know that manager called it subclass your component (JButton, JList etc), override method `getToolTipText()` and use `new Trowable().getStackTrace()` to identified that you are called from `TooltipManager.show()`

Good luck.